# how to add and get elements from 2Dimentions arrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to store arraylist of emails like:

RCPT TO: Rob@gmail.com

Mail From: Max@gmail.com

Body: hello, this is first email

```
 List<ArrayList<String>> allList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
 ArrayList<String> oneMail = new ArrayList<String>();



    oneMail.add("RCPT TO:  "+ Main.getRCPT());
    oneMail.add("MailFrom: "+ Main.getFrom());
    oneMail.add("Body: " + Main.getBody());
```

when print size of oneList I can see the size, which is here 3

I'm using this line to add oneMail arrayList to allList arryList, but not sure is it correct or not:

```
   allList.add(oneMail);
```

I stored three emails, but seems they don't stored in allList arrayList
when I print size of allList it gives 0,

how to add oneMail to allList, and more importantly, how to print all the content of allList.

however, I can't create another class as a requirement

thank you

=====

## edited

you are corrcet guys it gives me 1

however it gives zero when I place print size here in this method which supposed to print out the whole content of allList

```
  public void showall{

  // here gives zero and still until now gives zero
   System.out.print(allList.size()+"");


   // by this I want to print all elemnts of allList, which has number of emails

 for (int j = 0; j < allList.size() ; j++)
{

    for(int i = 0 ; i < oneMail.size();i++)
    {
    System.out.print(oneMail.get(i));

}   }
```

this method get called when I press retrieve button, which should print all sent mails

so in actionPerformed I'm just putting:

```
     showall();
```

where do think the mistake

thank you again guys

Comment: Working here : http://ideone.com/6uHtZG

Comment: Everything looks fine for me. Might be the issue is some where else. Please add full code.

Comment: I guess you are using wrong data structure. You should create a `Mail` class, and add those values as attributes. And maintain a `List<Mail>`.

Comment: Thank you @ZouZou , I have edited the question could u check for me thanks

Comment: I have edited the question @sᴜʀᴇsʜ ᴀᴛᴛᴀ, could u please help me finding the mistake

Comment: @mijcara When did you call this method ? Could you show your full code ?

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<ArrayList<String>> allList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
     ArrayList<String> oneMail = new ArrayList<String>();

        oneMail.add("RCPT TO:  recp@abc.com");
        oneMail.add("MailFrom: sender@abc.com");
        oneMail.add("Body: Body Of Mail");

        allList.add(oneMail);
        System.out.println(allList.size());
}
```

This is working fine for me. It prints 1

I guess you are using wrong data structure. You should create a `Mail` class, and add those values as attributes. And maintain a `List<Mail>`.

Answer (score 0):

Make a Java Object(e.g. Email with its members as Strings like from, to, body) to store Email information, and add each Email object into List.